# Why is the graph plotted by |V0| in lvdt characteristics graph

Tags: transducer

In the transfer characteristics of an LVDT , why is the modulus of voltage taken and not just the voltage. In both cases we can see linear range so, what is the advantage of taking mod V.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The magnitude |V| gives you the displacement from the center (null) position, whereas the phase can give you the sign.